# notify_url in paypal is failing

Tags: cakephp, paypal, paypal-ipn

i have checked IPN history in my sandbox paypal and i have figured out that it is not successfully notifying my notify_url. what could possibly be the reason? Perhaps i did not properly specify the location of my IPN controller where the action "process" is in. Please help.

```
'notify_url' => 'http://203.215.93.156/wifidrivescanportal/PaypalIpn/process' 
//'http://www.yoursite.com/paypal_ipn/process' 
//Notify_url... set this to the process path of your paypal_ipn::instant_payment_notification::process action
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your webserver or IP even reachable from the outside?

Check that your firewall and NAT (if used) is configured properly.

Log if anything is received in your process() controller action and check the log files.